# Bug in parsing JSON

Tags: java, android, json, list

I am trying to parse a json from a https request but there is a bug i can't  find. Here is the code for the class that takes as input a json sting and return a list of objects.

```
package com.example.ryzen.bakingapp;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONconvert {

private static final String RECIPE_ID = "id";
private static final String RECIPE_NAME = "name";
private static final String INGREDIENTS = "ingredients";
private static final String SERVINGS = "servings";
private static final String IMAGE = "image";
private static final String QUANTITY = "quantity";
private static final String MEASURE = "measure";
private static final String INGREDIENT = "ingredient";
private static final String STEP = "steps";
private static final String STEP_ID = "id";
private static final String SHORT_DESCRIPTION = "shortDescription";
private static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String VIDEO_URL = "videoURL";
private static final String THUMBNAIL = "thumbnailURL";

public static List<Recipe> convert (String json) {

    List<Recipe> recipesList = new ArrayList<>();
    int recipeId = 0;
    String name = "";
    int servings = 0;
    String image = "";
    List<Steps> steps = new ArrayList<>();
    String thumbnailURL = "";
    String videoURL = "";
    String description = "";
    String shortDescription = "";
    int stepId = 0;
    List<Ingredients> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
    float quantity = 0;
    String measure = "";
    String ingredient = "";

    try {

        JSONArray baseJsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int i = 0; i < baseJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            ingredients.clear();
            steps.clear();
            JSONObject recipeObject = baseJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            recipeId = recipeObject.getInt(RECIPE_ID);
            name = recipeObject.getString(RECIPE_NAME);
            servings = recipeObject.getInt(SERVINGS);
            image = recipeObject.getString(IMAGE);
            JSONArray ingredientsArray  = recipeObject.getJSONArray(INGREDIENTS);
            for (int j = 0; j < ingredientsArray.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject ingredientObject = ingredientsArray.getJSONObject(j);
                quantity = ingredientObject.getInt(QUANTITY);
                measure = ingredientObject.getString(MEASURE);
                ingredient = ingredientObject.getString(INGREDIENT);
                ingredients.add(new Ingredients(quantity,measure,ingredient));
            }
            JSONArray stepArray = recipeObject.getJSONArray(STEP);
            for (int k = 0; k < stepArray.length(); k++) {
                JSONObject stepsObject = stepArray.getJSONObject(k);
                stepId = stepsObject.getInt(STEP_ID);
                shortDescription = stepsObject.getString(SHORT_DESCRIPTION);
                description = stepsObject.getString(DESCRIPTION);
                videoURL = stepsObject.getString(VIDEO_URL);
                thumbnailURL = stepsObject.getString(THUMBNAIL);
                steps.add(new Steps(stepId, shortDescription,description,videoURL,thumbnailURL));
            }
            recipesList.add(new Recipe(recipeId, name, servings, image, ingredients, steps));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return recipesList; }
```

[This](https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/baking.json) is the json file i am trying to parse. So according to the above my Ingredients List should contain the following:

```
Graham Cracker crumbs
unsalted butter, melted
granulated sugar
salt
vanilla
Nutella or other chocolate-hazelnut spread
Mascapone Cheese(room temperature)
heavy cream(cold)
cream cheese(softened)
Bittersweet chocolate (60-70% cacao)
unsalted butter
granulated sugar
light brown sugar
large eggs
vanilla extract
all purpose flour
cocoa powder
salt
semisweet chocolate chips
sifted cake flour
granulated sugar
baking powder
salt
vanilla extract, divided
egg yolks
whole milk
unsalted butter, softened and cut into 1 in. cubes
egg whites
melted and cooled bittersweet or semisweet chocolate
Graham Cracker crumbs
unsalted butter, melted
granulated sugar
salt
vanilla,divided
cream cheese, softened
large whole eggs
large egg yolks
heavy cream
```

But instead i get this list of ingredients

```
Graham Cracker crumbs
unsalted butter, melted
granulated sugar
salt
vanilla,divided
cream cheese, softened
large whole eggs
large egg yolks
heavy cream
Graham Cracker crumbs
unsalted butter, melted
granulated sugar
salt
vanilla,divided
cream cheese, softened
large whole eggs
large egg yolks
heavy cream
Graham Cracker crumbs
unsalted butter, melted
granulated sugar
salt
vanilla,divided
cream cheese, softened
large whole eggs
large egg yolks
heavy cream
Graham Cracker crumbs
unsalted butter, melted
granulated sugar
salt
vanilla,divided
cream cheese, softened
large whole eggs
large egg yolks
heavy cream
```

It seems that the first Ingredients object is repeated and added everytime in the Ingredients list . But i can't understand why this is happening. Do you see anything that i am missing? Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you are using the same list to add your ingredients each time your parse a new recipe. Since you are using ingredients.clear(), that means the reference/pointer to the list "ingredients" remain the same each time you create a new Recipe object.

When you are listing your ingredients from the different recipes after this parsing, they are all the same, since they all access the same list, which of course only contains the last ingredients you found.

What you should do is create a new List for each recipe, and not re-use the same one :)

Comment: Yep, that worked .Thank you very for your time and explanation. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the same `ingredients` and `steps` arrays for each `Recipe`, resetting it in between and replacing contents with new entries. (It is actually the last entry that gets repeated over.)

Instead of calling `clear()` on your arrays, you can reinit it with `new ArrayList<>()` so that you get a new array and won't be modifying an array you've passed to a `Recipe`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, helped a lot.